# Processing a math paper written in TeX to generate a summary

Tags: programming

I'm interested in writing a program that can automatically process math papers written in TeX in order to generate summaries. I have partly finished one written in Python but it does not seem to work very well because people use different names for theorems, lemmas, etc to the point that they can't simply be captured by `\begin{theorem}`. I believe a part of the problem is that Python can not really natively process the LaTeX language. May I ask whether there is any way for TeX to selectively not process certain texts?

Here are what I want to retain in a summary:

1. Title, authors, abstract.
2. New commands and other settings.
3. Sections, subsections and subsubsections.
4. Theorems, lemmas, definitions, corollaries, conjectures, notations, examples, exercises and prepositions, all beginning with `\begin{something}` and ending with `\end{something}`.
5. Bibliography.

Basically most of the text needs to be somehow ignored. My current approach is letting a lexer and a parser written in Python spot what needs to be retained.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem and illustrates exactly what you want ignored. If you definition is everything from of the form `\begin{something}...\end{somthing}`, I assume you want exclude `somthing=document.` Do you want to exclude lists, etc...

Comment: ...I agree. Can you provide some input LaTeX file and the expected output (summary) that you want from that input?

Comment: I think this is not something that you are going to get a complete solution at the start. This needs to be built up over time.  The best way I can think of getting started on this is to provide a _very small_ document with one or two environments you want extracted along with one or two that you want ignored.

Comment: I assume you mean LaTeX and not TeX, since the later doesn't have enough structure to actually process.  But why not catch all `\begin{somethings}` and then figure out what "somethings" you're want to catch, and which you want to ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a short [Python script](https://github.com/mathyingzhou/math-tex-standardizer/blob/master/theoremextractor.py) written using TexSoup that can do at least 4. For now I'm satisfied. The next step is converting a math paper in tex into a plain text that can represent the same mathematical but not typesetting information unrelated to math.